# Why does the finite difference script for solving Poisson equation not work for delta function charge? How to fix it?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, computational-physics, software, dirac-delta-distributions

I know the charge density at the plates of a capacitor, from which the applied voltage and potential profile is to be calculated. Using the finite difference method in MATLAB script I solved the Poisson's equation that gives the correct result for all kind of continuous charge profiles. I checked constant (step function), linearly increasing/decreasing charge profile, in all cases numerical results agree with analytically calculated potential profile. But when I put the delta-function charge to study the original problem (in figure), it gives spooky results. (With $\rho=13.2$$\mu$C/$cm^2$, $\epsilon_r$=30, $x$=20nm, I would expect the voltage to be **9.92V**,while I am getting **40nV!**)

In the finite different approach:

$d^2V/dx^2$=-$\rho(x)$/$\epsilon$ in matrix form is $Au$=$h^2$$f$, where $f$=-[$\rho(i)$/$\epsilon$]' and $i$=1,2,......n are the discrete nodes. In my problem, I have $-\rho(1)$=$\rho(n)$=$13.2$$\mu$C/$cm^2$, and $\rho(i)=0$ elsewhere. Therefore I take  $f$=$-\rho(i)$/$\epsilon$[-1 0 0 0 .......... 0 0 0 1]'. Then potential is obtained by $u$=$A^{-1}$$f$

My question is, what is the physical reason for such anomaly?

How can I solve this issue and make this code work?
[image]
[image]

***Code:***

```
clc;

clear all;

t=20;  %Thickness value in nm

epsil_r=30; 

epsil=epsil_r*8.854*10^-14; %In CGS unit


n=500;              %Number of grid points


x1=0; x2=t*10^-7; %Thickness in cm


x=linspace(x1,x2,n);h=x(2)-x(1);


rho=13.2*10^-6;     %Strength of delta-function charge, C/cm^2

A=diag(-2*ones(1,n))+diag(ones(1,n-1),1)+diag(ones(1,n-1),-1);

A(n,n)=-1;        %Neumann boundary at right node

f=-rho/(epsil)*[-1;zeros(n-2,1);1]; %Right hand side of Poisson.

u=inv(A)*[h^2*f];              %Potential
```

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I think people will be hesitant to discuss the _physical_ behaviour of a simulation whose code they could not verify ... ;)

Comment: "What is the physical reason for such anomaly?" Either your computer is broken, or (more likely) there is a bug in your code. If you want the code debugged without showing it to anybody you need a mind-reading forum, not SE.

Comment: Dear altruist, I added the code in the question. I was wondering if there is anything fundamental for which delta-function charge can not be used, or it is all about my code. I am expecting your guideline.

Comment: I don't understand the code in this question. There's a bunch of definitions, but I don't see what actually acts on those objects. How you plot things is not important, what's important is how you solve things.

Comment: I added a description of the code as well. I don't get which of the definition you are talking about? "t" is the thickness of the capacitor, "epsil_r" is the relative dielectric constant, x1 and x2 are the coordinates of starting and ending point of the capacitor, h=x(2)-x(1)=$\delta$x. @EmilioPisanty?

Comment: Using python in a near 1:1 translation of yours, I get 9.92 mV at the right boundary. Also, why do you use 13.2*10^-6 when you can write it as 13.2e-6 and not (possibly) lose any precision due to floating-point math?

Answer (score 1):

**Your units don't add up.** You're solving for the equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2 u}{\mathrm dx^2} = f
$$
where $f = \rho/\epsilon$. If you take your solution at face value, then $u$ will have the dimensionality
\begin{align}
[u] & = [h^2 f] = [h^2\rho/\epsilon_0] = [Q/\epsilon_0].
\end{align}
Since $[\epsilon_0]=[Q/(VL)]$, this means that $[u]=[VL]$, a voltage times length, which is obviously not what you intended. Since the units don't match up, it is meaningless to talk about inconsistencies in the numbers - if you did this in some other unit system you would get a different answer.

The problem is in your handling of the surface charge associated with the delta function. The right-hand side of the Poisson equation requires a legitimate volumetric charge density, or something dimensionally equivalent to that. If $\sigma$ is a surface charge density, with $[\sigma]=[Q/L^2]$, then 
$$\rho(x,y,z) = \sigma\delta(x-x_0)$$
is a correct volumetric charge density because $[\delta(x-x_0)] = [1/L]$, but your discretization procedure has dropped this fact out.

To fix this, I would suggest dropping the pretense that you have a true singular charge density and instead model it as a finite slab of thickness $d$ and volumetric charge density $\sigma/d$, where you can set $d$ to your discretization length if you want. Ultimately, the value of $d$ should be unimportant to your finite result - but it's crucial that you get your units right.

Comment: Thank you very much, its giving perfect result now. I just needed to convert the surface charge density into "per volume" unit. @Emilio Pisanty